# SED- combine matching regex lines to make a csv file

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I was wondering if it is possible to use sed to create a csv file by combining multiple lines together onto a singe line separate by commas.

For example I have written a sed statement that retrieves the lines I want.

```
sed -n -e '/ENTITIES/,/ENDSEC/p' | sed -n -e '/  8/{n;p;}' -e '/ 10/{n;p;}' -e '/ 20/{n;p;}' -e '/ 11/{n;p;}' -e '/ 21/{n;p;}' < Test.txt > out.csv
```

Which produces the output;

```
 0
 4.93
 9.04
 27.9
 23.4
 0
 34.56
 0.77
 66.65
 19.50
 0
 55.26
 47.29
 53.42
 19.75
 0
 -18.22
 44.35
 19.74
 53.28
```

But I would Like it to output;

```
 0,4.93,9.04,27.9,23.4
 0,34.56,0.77,66.65,19.50
 0,55.26,47.29,53.42,19.75
 0,-18.22,44.35,19.74,53.28
```

Is there anyway to do this without a pipe? Id Rather not invoke another command as the files I process are upwards of 100 mil lines or so.

Thanks in advance for your help!

To add, here is a portion of my input file;

More Stuff Above

```
AcDbBlockEnd
  0
ENDSEC
  0
SECTION
  2
ENTITIES
  0
LINE
  5
1B1
330
1F
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbLine
 10
4.933855223957067
 20
9.042372500389475
 30
0.0
 11
27.92566226775641
 21
23.49207557886149
 31
0.0
  0
LINE
  5
1B2
330
1F
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbLine
 10
34.56437535704545
 20
0.778745874786317
 30
0.0
 11
66.65564369957746
 21
19.50612180407816
 31
0.0
  0
LINE
  5
1B3
330
1F
100
AcDbEntity
  8
0
100
AcDbLine
 10
55.26446832764479
 20
47.29118282642324
 30
0.0
 11
53.42718194719286
 21
19.75092411476788
 31
0.0
  0
LINE
  5
1B4
330
1F
100
AcDbEntity
ENDSEC
  0
```

More stuff below.

Comment: Kinda tricky to suggest looking at the intermediate output. You should post your original file and explain the desired output.

Comment: looks that the `0` line is the record separator (Hi Jaypal!). Good luck to all.

Comment: The sample input, when supplied to your code, does _not_ produce your sample output.  Would you clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: Right, the sample input does not produce the exact sample output. I manually truncated the sample output for simplicity. So things like 4.933855223957067 and 9.042372500389475 I truncated to 4.93 and 9.04. Also it looks like the sample input only produces the first tree lines of the sample output. Like I said, just samples as the actual input is upward of 100 million lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it Thanks to ooga! Before I lacked the understanding of hold space vs. pattern space, now it has all become clear!

```
sed -n '
    /ENTITIES/,/ENDSEC/{
         /  8/{n;h;};
         / 10/{n;H;};
         / 20/{n;H;};
         / 11/{n;H;};
         / 21/{n;H;g;s/\n/,/g;p};
    }
' < Test.dxf > out.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this might be what you're looking for, but as jaypal said, without seeing the input it's somewhat of a guess.

```
sed -n '
  /ENTITIES/,/ENDSEC/p
  /  8/{n;h}
  / 10/{n;H}
  / 20/{n;H}
  / 11/{n;H}
  / 21/{n;H;g;s/\n/,/g;p}
' Test.txt > out.csv
```

With comments:

```
sed -n '
  /ENTITIES/,/ENDSEC/p
  /  8/{n;h}       # store next line in hold space
  / 10/{n;H}       # append next line to hold space (after newline)
  / 20/{n;H}       # ditto
  / 11/{n;H}       # ditto
  / 21/{n;H;       # ditto
        g;         # put hold space into pattern space
        s/\n/,/g;  # substitute commas for newlines
        p          # print it
       }
' Test.txt > out.csv
```

Comment: @jaypal Thanks, man. Always good to hear from a fellow sed-head. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the great responce. Unfortunately it doesn't quite work, the whole input file prints. Every line before the "ENTITIES" and after "ENDSEC" have a comma inserted at the beginning. Lines between the "ENTITIES" and "ENDSEC" have commas inserted at the beginning of the line immediately after the "/   8/" "/   10/" "/   20/" "/   11/" "/   21/" regex. It's VERY CLOSE TO WORKING !!! Just a few more tweaks I guess? @jaypal

Comment: @Mike Try removing the first line of the script (i.e., get rid of the `/ENTITIES/,/ENDSEC/p` part).

Comment: Thanks ogga! I figured it out, I received a dos version of the file (different newline character) so converted it to nix. Also if you replace `/ENTITIES/,/ENDSEC/p` with `/ENTITIES/,/ENDSEC/{` and add a `}` before the `' Test.txt > out.csv` The code works perfectly! See my answer below. Thanks so much for your help, couldn't have done it without you!

Answer (score 1):

Just pipe your sed to

```
sed 'your long sed commnand' | paste -d, - - - - -
```

the result will be

```
0,4.93,9.04,27.9,23.4
0,34.56,0.77,66.65,19.50
0,55.26,47.29,53.42,19.75
0,-18.22,44.35,19.74,53.28
```